# How to find the standard deviations of lattice parameters after Rietveld refinement with GSASII?

Tags: experimental-chemistry, crystal-structure, crystallography

I am trying to learn how to use GSASII. It is different from GSAS/EXPGUI, so I feel hard to find some information from GSASII interface. I want to find what are the values for the standard deviations of lattice parameters after Rietveld refinement. How can I check it?

Answer (score 1):

I assume you are looking for the values of "estimated standard deviation, e.s.d." (also called standard uncertainty, s.u.).

You may find the values by exporting the result into a cif file. Click Export > Entire project as > Full CIF